# How to get autocomplete functionality for included PHP templates in IDEs

Tags: php, netbeans, phpstorm, phpdoc

```
class Controller {

  protected $property1;

  protected function getUid(){
    ...
  }

  public function render($template, array $data){
     extract($data);
     ob_start();
     include $template;
     return ob_get_clean();
  }
}
```

Template `example.php` to be rendered in `Controller::render()`

```
<div><?php echo $this->getUid(); ?></div>
```

How to get autocomplete suggestions inside `example.php` for all methods and properties in Controller class? I'm using NetBeans and PhpStorm. Can I add reference to the class in template's PHPDoc block?

Comment: In PhpStorm you can typehint `$this` using `@var` PHPDoc.

Comment: @var was my first attempt and it doesn't work in this case

Comment: It works -- I'm using it in my old projects in PhpStorm. How did you declare it and where? Please provide examples.

Comment: Ups, I was trying it in NetBeans because NB runs faster. Yes, PHPStorm is smarter

Answer (score 3):

Just use PHPDoc comment with `@var` tag to typehint `$this` -- works fine in PhpStorm.

[image]

**Please note:**

- By default IDE will show **public methods/properties only**.
- To see protected/private members you will have to invoke code completion one more time -- <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> (or whatever else you may have there on your computer/keymap).